# calculate amazon s3 price for my cooking video site

Tags: cloud

we have a website which has tons of cooking video, and since the price is getting higher every month (due to the increasing bandwidth) we're thinking of moving the videos to amazon's cloud storage. but being a total noob in this area, and amazon's site doesn't really help people like me understand what I really need and how to calculate the bills... so here goes

1) the videos will be in .mp4 and .flv, and visitors will play the videos directly from the website. so which amazon's package should I choose? Is it amazon s3?

2) if it's amazon s3, how do i use this calculator at amazon's website? this is what I did: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKv1j.png

3) again, i don't know how to calculate using the amazon calculator, and what figures i do need to provide. here's my cpanel bandwidth log for the last 3 months: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWM8z.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To estimate your usage correctly, put the 700 GB figure in "Data Transfer Out" in the pricing calculator, not in "Data Transfer In".

Comment: that's all, is it? what is PUT/COPY/POST/LIST Requests, GET and Other Requests, and Reduced Redundancy Storage? thanks

Comment: GET requests are simply downloads of each file. The others correspond to methods of uploading or editing your files on S3. The cost of these should be negligible. And Amazon's explanation of [reduced redundancy storage](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/05/19/announcing-amazon-s3-reduced-redundancy-storage/) is better than I could write in a small comment.